# Can't solve optimization problem using greedy algorithm

Tags: arrays, optimization, greedy

I encountered a problem during a company's online assessment a few months ago and I'm still struggling to solve it. The problem involves optimizing the purchase of items over a certain number of days given a set of pricing offers.

The function, takes 2 array as input

`items_per_day = [1,5,3,4,2]`

`price_offers = [`
`[1,3,2,1],`
`[1,1,3,4],`
`[3,5,5,6]`
`]`

first array indicate how many item we buy in the day (items_per_day)
ex:

`[1,5,3,4,2]`

we buy 1 item in day 1,
5 item in day 2,
3 item in day 3 and so on

2nd array is for price (2d array)

ex:

`[ [1,3,2,1],  [1,1,3,4],  [3,5,5,6] ]`

the array is
`[startDay, endDay, price, numberYouCanBuy]`

`[1,3, 2, 1]`

-> you can buy maximum 1 item that cost 2 dollar if we buy it between day 1 and day 3 (include day 1 and day 3)

`[1,1,3,4]`

->you can buy maximum 4 item that cost 3 dollar if we buy it in day 1

`[3,5,5,6]`

-> you can buy maximum 6 item that cost 5 dollar if we buy it between day 3 and day 5 (include day 1 and day 3)

you could assume we're able to find a price for every day
how could we output the minimum cost from the input

if we have a items_per_day as `[0,1,1]`, and price array that look like this

`[ [2,2,2,1], [2,3,1,1], [3,3,5,1] ]`

if I use greedy, I will choose offer `[2,3,1,1]` in day 2, and `[3,3,5,1]` in day 3, which total cost is 1 + 5 = 6
but we should choose offer `[2,2,2,1]` in day 2, and `[2,3,1,1]` in day 3, which total cost is 2 + 1 = 3

Thank you for help

Comment: First, there could be that this problem doesn't have a greedy solution...
But, we can consider it "greedy" in another way: for days 2,3 we need to pick two items from 3 that cost: 1,2 and 5. since we need to pick only 2 we can try and be greedy and choose 1 + 2 and see if it works (and it does in our case), but in general, in case it doesn't, we should try 1 + 5 and only if it doesn't work as well pick 2+5. So maybe the greediness is on the sum of prices and not on the first day.